# how to preselect dropdown value from database when dropdown list is loaded from jquery load method

Tags: java, jquery, servlets

I'm not entirely sure if this is possible, but I'll ask here.

I have a .jsp page that populates the dropdown contents from .txt files and loaded using jquery/javascript.

They're loaded like this:

```
$function(){  
$(".dropdownA").load("dropdowninfo.txt);  
};
```

I also use a servlet to ping the database to fill out the other information for this particular .jsp page.  My question is how to select the proper value of what's in the dropdown menu to show that value.

For example:
if the dropdown contained {a, b, c, d, e}  and the servlet returned "d", how can i get the jsp page to show the "d".  Currently it will show the list.  Below is how I coded the jsp page.

```
<select class=".dropdownA"><select>
```

This will display a, b, c, d, e in the dropdown.  So how would you preselect "d"?  Or should i just do it all from the servlet, including populating the dropdown?

Thanks!

**Update:**

The servlet runs a query, and returns the results to the jsp page.  For example:

```
ResultsSet results = record.executeQuery();
Result result = ResultSupport.toResult(results);
request.setAttribute("result", result);
RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispacher("/page.jsp");
rd.forward(request, response);
```

So on the jsp page, I get the corresponding value by calling:
    c:out value="${result[x]}"

In essence, somehow i need to put ${result[x]} as the preselected value of the select list.

Comment: How is the value coming back? As HTML? JSON?

Comment: it comes back in a JSTL format, so ${value[x]}

Comment: Perhaps I should re-phrase that: what is sent back to the browser? "${value[x]}" is not sent to the browser, that's your server-side code.

Comment: well, i'll update the top on how the servlet is submitting the data to the page.  I hope that clears this up.

Answer (score 1):

To pre-select an option using jQuery you just use val().

e.g:

```
$('.dropdownA').val('b');
```

So, after you populate the dropdown, probably in the callback of your load method, you should then set the value as above.

Answer (score 0):

If the value returned from the Database id for example say c. Then you can try this

```
$('.dropdownA').val('c)
```

This will preselect the dropdown for you